# Keycloak 21.1 REST API Endpoint

Tags: java, rest, keycloak, quarkus

I've been trying to implement this custom endpoint in keycloak 21.1:

**EndopintFactory.java file**

```
package org.keycloak.extension.authenticator;

import org.keycloak.Config;
import org.keycloak.models.KeycloakSession;
import org.keycloak.models.KeycloakSessionFactory;
import org.keycloak.services.resource.RealmResourceProvider;
import org.keycloak.services.resource.RealmResourceProviderFactory;

public class HashRegistrationEndpointFactory implements RealmResourceProviderFactory {

    public static final String ID = "custom-registration-endpoint";

    @Override
    public RealmResourceProvider create(KeycloakSession session) {
        return new HashRegistrationEndpoint();
    }

    @Override
    public void init(Config.Scope config) {
    }

    @Override
    public void postInit(KeycloakSessionFactory factory) {
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
    }

    @Override
    public String getId() {
        return ID;
    }
}
```

**Endpoint java file:**

```
package org.keycloak.taxit.authenticator;

import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.jboss.logging.Logger;
import org.keycloak.models.KeycloakSession;
import org.keycloak.services.resource.RealmResourceProvider;

import javax.ws.rs.*;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class HashRegistrationEndpoint implements RealmResourceProvider {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(HashRegistrationEndpoint.class);

    @Context
    private KeycloakSession session;

    @GET
    @Path("/hash-register")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response customRegister(
            @QueryParam("hash") String hash,
            @QueryParam("issuer") String issuer,
            @QueryParam("email") String email,
            @QueryParam("ruc") String ruc,
            @QueryParam("isValidId") String isValidId) {

        // Set parameters in the authentication session
        session.getContext().getAuthenticationSession().setAuthNote("hash", hash);
        session.getContext().getAuthenticationSession().setAuthNote("issuer", issuer);
        session.getContext().getAuthenticationSession().setAuthNote("email", email);
        session.getContext().getAuthenticationSession().setAuthNote("ruc", ruc);
        session.getContext().getAuthenticationSession().setAuthNote("isValidId", isValidId);

        // Create a map and put the query parameters into it
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("hash", hash);
        map.put("issuer", issuer);
        map.put("email", email);
        map.put("ruc", ruc);
        map.put("isValidId", isValidId);

        // Return the map as a JSON object
        return Response.ok().entity(map).build();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getResource() {
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
    }
}
```

**META-INF/org.keycloak.services.resource.RealmResourceProviderFactory**:

```
org.keycloak.taxit.authenticator.HashRegistrationEndpointFactory
```

After writing the code I built the jar file and put it inside the /providers folder of the keycloak server folder.

Then i ran the commands:

```
kc.bat build
kc.bat start-dev
```

The server runs fine but when i try to access the endpoint **http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/realm_name/custom-registration-endpoint/hash-register?hash=a&issuer=b&email=c&ruc=d&isValidId=e** in a browser the responses is 404.

Is there something wrong with the URL or something I'm missing from the programming/configuration of keycloak?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the URL without the `/auth`. Since Keycloak 17 the `/auth` was removed from the default context path.

References:

- https://www.keycloak.org/migration/migrating-to-quarkus

Answer (score 1):

Try with `http://localhost:8080/realms/realm_name/custom-registration-endpoint/hash-register?hash=a&issuer=b&email=c&ruc=d&isValidId=e`.

Since Keycloak 17 the “/auth” context has been removed. But you can set the relative path using `--http-relative-path` configuration.

So, you can run these commands to start Keycloak to still use /auth.

```
kc.bat build
kc.bat start-dev --http-relative-path /auth
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone, the the path without **/auth**  is the correct one, but the reason it was not working was because i got this error and was redirected to 404 page:

```
2024-01-10 14:19:17,460 ERROR [org.keycloak.services.error.KeycloakErrorHandler] (executor-thread-0) Uncaught server error: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.keycloak.models.KeycloakSession.getContext()" because "this.session" is null
```

specifically at the line where I'm trying to invoke **session.getContext().** in this part

```
 @Context
    private KeycloakSession session;

    @GET
    @Path("/hash-register")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response customRegister(
            @QueryParam("hash") String hash,
            @QueryParam("issuer") String issuer,
            @QueryParam("email") String email,
            @QueryParam("ruc") String ruc,
            @QueryParam("isValidId") String isValidId) {

        // Set parameters in the authentication session
        session.getContext().getAuthenticationSession().setAuthNote("hash", hash);
```

Anyways the endpoint already works, so the session error might be another problem not related to this question. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

The `KeycloakSession` is null because in the latest versions we are discouraging using dependency injection for this bean. See https://www.keycloak.org/docs/23.0.4/upgrading/#context-and-dependency-injection-no-longer-enabled-to-jax-rs-resources.

Ideally, you should pass the session from your factory when creating provider instances.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, dependency injection using `@Context` annotation is removed. You should pass session from factory class and intialize session through the constructor.

Factory class

```
public class HashRegistrationEndpointFactory implements RealmResourceProviderFactory {

public static final String ID = "custom-registration-endpoint";

@Override
public RealmResourceProvider create(KeycloakSession session) {
    return new HashRegistrationEndpoint(session);
}
....
```

Provider class

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class HashRegistrationEndpoint implements RealmResourceProvider {

private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(HashRegistrationEndpoint.class);

private KeycloakSession session;

public HashRegistrationEndpoint(KeycloakSession session){
this.session = session;
}
....
```